# ¿Podríamos resaltar de algún modo el enlace de editar?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, interfaz-de-usuario

Quizá soy el único al que le pasa, pero cuando quiero editar una pregunta o una respuesta tengo que mirar dos veces para encontrar el enlace "editar".

Eso me lleva a pensar que quizá los novatos no son conscientes de que existe esa funcionalidad (no se ve al primer vistazo) y por eso vemos muy a menudo que cuando pedimos más información la añadan como comentario (lo que es especialmente doloroso cuando es código).

Comment: El resaltarlo es cosa de los developers. Para ello seria mejor una publicacion en Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @lois6b creo que sería un caso muy especial para SO español. Por lo regular los OP nuevos no lo encuentran.

Comment: Yo prefiero que siga teniendo la misma estética que todos los sitios de la red... Seamos sinceros, bastante claro (y grande, y resaltado) está en el [tour], y aún así no lo leen. No creo que resaltándolo vayan a verlo. Al contrario, creo que jugaría muy en contra de la UX en SOes